# How to subtract a non-stationary background in real time

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, slam-algorithm

I know that have some opencv algorthms ( [here](http://docs.opencv.org/master/db/d5c/tutorial_py_bg_subtraction.html) and [here](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/dc5/tutorial_background_subtraction.html), for example) that handles effectiveness with stationary background subtraction. But i need do this in a non-stationary background. Thus using Hand-held camera.
I would appreciate if someone could give some tips.

Comment: you simply cannot do that.. at least, is not so simple http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~yaser/SheikhJavedKanade_ICCV_2009.pdf

Comment: @Miki my goal is recognizing a plenty of moving objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segmentation of a dynamic scene is a topic of ongoing research in CV... However, for a quick win, you might want to try [this rather nice library](https://github.com/andrewssobral/bgslibrary). It builds beyond OpenCV and provides 37 different algorithms for you to try - perhaps one might work well for your use-case. Good luck!

Comment: nice link, but it seems it is for static camera only. Or I missed something?

Comment: If you are referring to motion ambiguity (i.e. camera versus scene change) that’s a very good point - and a key issue for any segmentation algorithm. Off the top of my head I believe many of the more sophisticated spatial-temporal models go some way to address this (at least for short sequences of change) - e.g. LOBSTER which is included in the BGS lib http://www.polymtl.ca/litiv/doc/StCharlesBilodeauWACV2014.pdf

Comment: However, you are right that the vast majority of algorithms in this library assume the static camera (with possibly some short-term jitter) - since they evaluate it on the BMC traffic dataset. Perhaps this paper is then more relevant for this question: http://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~elgammal/pub/ECCV12_Elqursh.pdf

Comment: @Graver, Nice paper! Add this link to your answer, since it would be a nice way to go

Comment: Thank you very much. It's A relevant reference.

Comment: How do i use it with android